# Whatsapp shared id

Tags: facebook, cloud, message, whatsapp

Have a meta developer account and a app connected to this developer dashboard.After integrating the Facebook embedded signuop flow in our app we get a code and using that I retrieve the access token and the WhatsApp shared id.

Now when I am making a request in the endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/251530491378777/messages. with payload
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"to": recipient number,
"text": {"body": "hi"}
}
I am getting the response like
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '251530491378777' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "AlrNtcSrDo3-JtMk6sUfqXW"
}
}
I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me